# JQuery Mobile Sub page

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

As I know that in JQuery Mobile, every page changing is equivalent to create new "page" div, Can we just change a portion in the "content" of the page, something like subpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. jQuery Mobile doesn't require you to manage pages by creating additional `div` element in the same HTML file - you can do it perfectly fine in a different HTML file and make a transition to it (perhaps with `data-prefetch` attribute set) using `<a>`.
2. Nothing prevents you from writing a jQuery plug-in, jQuery UI plug-in or (scary though, I know) pure JavaScript that will alter the contents of the DOM element dynamically and manage pages loading according to data received from server - with necessary calls to things of the `listview('refresh')` ilk - to ensure proper styling.

With that said you have to ask yourself two things:

1. Why do you need to do it? Can't you manage by pre-creating the page using jQuery Mobile paradigm and just retrieving and inserting the data into the new page?
2. What will the performance implication (if any) will be, if I have to perform DOM manipulations on every 'page transition'?

As a side note - jQuery Mobile provides you with methods that allow for page manipulation:

`$.mobile.changePage` and `$.mobile.loadPage` that you can use (look at `pageContainer` option).

[See API docs here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/methods.html)

Comment: thank you @ZenMaster :)... I was too into the JQuery Mobile that forgot I what I really needed.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to use right now a jQueryMobile plugin for subpages: https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget

I didn't make it work yet but i think it should work :).